# How do I get mode editor

Tags: node-editor

Im a complete noob at blender and im trying to find node editor but I cant? Could someone just explain the steps to find it please haha.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to blender! :)

Its called "shader editor" since > Version 2.8

For a better start you can check out the Blender Manual (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor.html) and also the official Youtube Series Blender Fundamentals (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zrd37k2tJM)

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! I kept trying texture node editor and was so confused when it wasn't the right thing

Comment: no problem, glad i could help :) maybe you could edit your answer to "node" instead of "mode", so other users could find it more easily. Also if you liked the answer please consider marking it as solved ;)